# How to make a line and dot plot with the range of date and time in r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Here is an example data:

```
> WakeTime <- strptime(c("2017/5/1 08:12", "2017/5/1 08:30", "2017/5/2 
08:00", "2017/5/2 04:50"), format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
> SleepTime <- strptime(c("2017/5/1 20:30", "2017/5/1 21:13", "2017/5/2 
22:15", "2017/5/3 01:00"), format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")

> timetable <- data.frame(WakeTime,SleepTime);timetable
             WakeTime           SleepTime
1 2017-05-01 08:12:00 2017-05-01 20:30:00
2 2017-05-01 08:30:00 2017-05-01 21:13:00
3 2017-05-02 08:00:00 2017-05-02 22:15:00
4 2017-05-02 04:50:00 2017-05-03 01:00:00
```

I am trying to draw a line from the `WakeTime` to the `SleepTime` in a plot where x is 24h time and y is month and day. I tried so many ways but I still having trouble with the range of hours.

In case you need the extra code:

```
> WMonthDay <- as.Date(WakeTime,format = "%b/%d")
> SMonthDay <- as.Date(SleepTime,format = "%b/%d")
> Whm <- format(WakeTime, "%H:%M")
> Shm <- format(SleepTime, "%H:%M")
> Supertimetable <- data.frame(WMonthDay,SMonthDay,Whm,Shm);Supertimetable
   WMonthDay  SMonthDay   Whm   Shm
1 2017-05-01 2017-05-01 08:12 20:30
2 2017-05-01 2017-05-01 08:30 21:13
3 2017-05-02 2017-05-02 08:00 22:15
4 2017-05-02 2017-05-03 04:50 01:00
```

P.S. Is there anyway to show the `WakeTime` to the `SleepTime` as two different of color dots in the same plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With these helper functions

```
library(hms)
date_only <- function(x)
    as.Date(strftime(x, "%Y-%m-%d"))
time_only <- function(x)
    as.hms(x-date_only(x))
```

You could do something like this

```
ggplot(timetable) + 
geom_segment(aes(x=time_only(WakeTime), xend=time_only(SleepTime),
    y=date_only(WakeTime), yend=date_only(SleepTime))) + 
geom_point(aes(x=time_only(WakeTime), y=date_only(WakeTime)), col="green") + 
geom_point(aes(x=time_only(SleepTime), y=date_only(SleepTime)), col="blue") + 
scale_x_time() + 
scale_y_date() + 
labs(x="Time", y="Date")
```

[image]

Comment: I got this warning: `Warning messages:
1: In as.hms(x - date_only(x)) :
  Incompatible methods ("-.POSIXt", "-.Date") for "-"`

Comment: It's just a warning. I guess you could do `time_only <- function(x) as.hms(x-as.POSIXct(date_only(x)))` if you wanted to.

Comment: Why you use x minus date_only(x)?